# i can't seem to open jupyter notebook anymore, even though I'm doing the same thing I used to

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Even if i go to the specific folder with my work, hit Open in Terminal, and then type in jupyter notebook, it keeps telling me

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe"  "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\jupyter.exe" notebook': The system cannot find the file specified.

also i used pip and not anoconda and i have version 3.11.6 for python

It's been weird ever since I restarted my computer a few weeks ago, I've never had this issue before that. any ideas on how to fix it? I can't even uninstall jupyter using the command prompt, and python works fine in VS Code

I've also tried deleting jupyter in the control panel, but it won't show up in the programs section and i dont want to delete python as a whole. then i tried just redownloading it using the pip command, but i got the same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

try using `pip install jupyter`, if that doesn't work, then it seems that jupyter and\or python are not installed properly on your machine, and you were using a Venv this entire time. try opening the python installer, you should have an option to repair the way python is installed. after that, `pip install jupyter` should work fine, and nothing should get deleted.

Comment: i ended up uninstalling python since it kept stopping in the middle of the repair thing, reinstalling it, installing pip because apparently i didnt have it??? even though i used it  to download jupyter last time, and now it works so thank you